# Is it possible to perform an operation before routing to views in django

Tags: django, view

I have the main urls.py that includes other apps urls.py, then calling the corresponding view. 
However, I have an operation that needs to be performed everytime before doing anything, whatever the app. Is it possible to perform an operation before routing to the view ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in *middleware*.

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Wiredly my router gets called before the middleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes what you describe here is [*middleware* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/). You can see middleware as a set of decorators that are wrapped over every request-response cycle: you thus have the freedom to perform certain tasks *before* the request is passed to the view, and *after* the response comes back from the view.

In fact you probably already use a lot of middleware without knowing: for example auhentication middleware that checks whether the user is logged in, and adds that to the request.

You can define your own middleware by defining a class, for example in `app/middleware.py` (taken from the documentation, and slightly modified):

```
# app/middleware.py

class MyMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        # ... (pre) ...

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # ... (post) ...

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

Here `get_response` is the decorator below it (well ultimately it is the view you are querying). You can thus add operations where here in comment `(pre)` and `(post)` are noted (respectively actions *before* and *after* control is passed to the view).

Then you can *register* your middleware, in the `settings.py` file:

```
#  settings.py

#  ...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.MyMiddleware'
]

# ...
```

Note that the order is important: for example `AuthenticationMiddleware` will add a `user` to the `request` object. If you thus run `MyMiddleware` before the `AuthenticationMiddleware` (put it higher in the list), you can not make use of `request.user`, unless you implement it yourself, but that would of course only result in duplicated code.

In some projects, some middleware can be ommitted. For example if your project would not require authentication, then certain middleware only makes the request-to-response process slower. By "throwing" the related middleware out, you thus reduce the amount of work that is done before a `request` reaches the view (and before the response the view provides is returned to the client).

By default, Django already adds some middleware to the `settings.py` file. You can inspect the implementation of (most of) this middleware in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py).